# Is it possible to create instance of an Interface(e.g-Map Interface)?If it is then how?

Tags: java, map

In most Java code, I see people declare Java objects like this:

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

instead of:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

How is it possible (i know it is but why) to create instance of a Map interface when we know that we can't create instance of an interface.Please explain.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A related question (but probably not a duplicate): http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/258105/why-return-back-or-assign-to-a-supertype-rather-than-the-implementation-type

Comment: *Both* lines of code create an instance of `HashMap`: that's what `new HashMap` does. The first one **assigns** that instance to a **variable** of type `Map`.

Answer (score 5):

It's called polymorphism:
The instance of a class can be treated as instance of that class but also as an instance of every interface the class implements, since it has to implement all the interface's methods. An interface is a contract that says: "The class implementing me offers at least the same operations that I offer."

Every HashMap is a Map, but not every Map is a HashMap.

Comment: Well you do get polymorphism from this. You can get polymorphism several different ways. This way is called inheritance. The generic collection just makes it a bit weird.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create an instance of an `interface`, because an `interface` is basically an abstract class without the restriction against multiple inheritance.
And an abstract class is missing parts of its implementation, or is explicitly marked as abstract to prohibit instantiation.

What you *can* do, and in your example did, is instantiating a class derived from (called implementing) said interface, and upcasting it to any base, be it interface, concrete class or abstract class.

Unless the implementer foolishly broke the contract, the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) applies and it works just like you actually had instantiated the `interface`.

Answer (score 2):

Java prohibits interfaces being used to create **objects**, but it does not prohibit them being used to create **variables**.

Consider what's actually happening in this code:

```
    Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

1. A **reference variable** is declared on the *stack* with a name *'hashMap'* and type `Map<String, String>`.
2. A `new` **instance** of type `HashMap<>` is created on the *heap*
3. The *'hashMap'* variable is assigned a **reference handle** (i.e. a memory address value) pertaining to the newly-created instance.

Note:

- a *variable* is a *named area of memory*, on the stack.
- an *object* is an *instance of a class*, on the heap.
- a *reference variable* is a *variable* for a *reference handle*.
- a *reference handle* is a *number* which represents the memory location of an object on the heap.

This is important because there are two "things" being created in memory, a reference variable and an object.    A reference variable is more than just a name for an object;   indeed a reference variable can keep a handle on any object, provided that object's type is compatible with the variable's type.

For example, all classes in Java are ultimately derived from `Object`, so a variable whose type is `Object` can reference any instance of any class.

However, a variable of type `Map<String, String>` can only reference an instance of a class which implements the `Map<String, String>` interface.

Ultimately, there is no problem with creating a variable from an interface, since reference variables do not support any behaviour in themselves (other than for garbage collection).     A reference variable is a way for a program to keep track of the objects allocated on the heap, and the type of a variable determines the operations that the program can perform on a referenced object.

Answer (score 1):

```
Map<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
```

The above statement does three things:

1. Create a new instance of `HashMap<String, String>`.
2. Create a variable that can hold a reference to a `Map<String, String>`.
3. Store the reference of the object created in step 1 in the variable created in step 2.

It's important to note that underlying object is still a `HashMap<String, String>`. Since `HashMap` implements the `Map` interface, it can be refereed to by a variable with the type `Map`. In the future, if you needed to change the map implementation, all you need to do is change what is done in step 1.

It's important to note that code that comes after this first line will only have access to methods defined in the `Map` interface.

For example:

```
interface SomeInterface {
  void foo();
}
class SomeClass implements SomeInterface {
  void foo() {
    // ...
  }
  void bar() {
    // ...
  }
}
// ...
SomeInterface thing = new SomeClass();
thing.foo(); // works
this.bar(); // doesn't compile because bar() is not defined in SomeInterface
```